# Small script creates a conflict

Tags: jquery

Here is my script. It works in all browsers. But.
 In the browser, Firefox, is continuously loading links pictures. After loading the image. That is, where is to be favicon rotated download process. How to stop it. I do not know.

Due to this one script does not work.
I repeat. When the picture is fully loaded script continues working...
Please help me fix this.

```
$(function(){
LoadImage();
function LoadImage(){
        var img_url = $("#img_url").val();
        if(img_url == ''){
            img_url = "preload_image/images/me-banner.png";
        }
        var img = new Image();
        $(img).load(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $('#img_holder').removeClass('loadit').append(img);
            $(img).fadeIn();

        }).attr('src',img_url);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is meanly for what? the favicon? if its for the favicon then you shold do something ells rather which will be simple to track any errors.

Comment: The script sends a request on.
That is the page because of this is constantly load. When all objects have long loaded. This can be stopped if you do 1 or 2 times refresh the page.

Comment: Must stop the query to load. Now only helps refresh.

Answer (score 0):

what if you try it like this in your document ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    LoadImage();
});

// and outside the document ready
function LoadImage() {
    var img_url = $("#img_url").val();
    if(img_url == ''){
        img_url = "preload_image/images/me-banner.png";
    }
    var img = new Image();
    $(img).load(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('#img_holder').removeClass('loadit').append(img);
        $(img).fadeIn();

    }).attr('src',img_url);
}
```

your function looks like its calling itself again

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately did not help. Everything as it was.